# Android sharing objects across Activities and Services using Application states vs Intents

Tags: android

I'm looking for some general advice on Intents vs Application context.

When you have an application with a service that performs some stuff like a threaded network listener, and/or gather location info, to be shared in a structured set with main Activity, and main Activity will have to on user input tweak said data, what would be the smartest way to share this data between these levels?

Right now I've got a setup using Intents but I don't like it, though it might do for now. I can't serialize the data in its entirety, so I'm broadcasting bits here and there. The main problem is the primary data set my Intents are used to update are stored in the main Activity.

I'd like to move the data set into my Service, or store it in an Application context. However I'm concerned about thread safety since the main Activity would occasionally tweak the data. e.g. on single press, change a boolean, or remove an item from the data set, etc...

I get the point of Intents, but I'd like to broadcast an Intent as a trigger for a function that needs data stored in the Application context, not as a vehicle for shuffling data (partial data) around an application.

Can I reasonably use an Application context to update and share data between a Service and Activity in a safe manner? I'd like my Service to run in the background and the Activity to pull or update the data set when the user returns to the app, or changes orientation. Thanks.

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION**

How about this. Is it safe to access a bound service getter/setter method for data sharing? I bind to my service to start/stop threaded functions through public methods, (its been a while since I jumped back on this and realized I was binding) can I safely call getter/setters in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to try create own solution, but rather think about MVC model.

If you need pass data between two [C]ontrollers (eg. Activity, Fragment, ...) you should persist them in [M]odel, which is implemented in way you can (de)serialize your data.

Whether to use SQlite (or some ORM), SharedPreferences, file storage (serialized json possibly), binary blob within file (see `ObjectOutputStream`,`ObjectInputStream`) or another [M]odel implementation, depends entirely on your custom use-case.

It's generaly **very nasty** idea to store data statically in context, because of way how system and user works with your application.

Think about some more use-case, such as making standalone thread to fetch and persist data into [M]odel. If your [M]odel will be some kind of static variable or application-context variable, you will always need to stick on it and work with such mess as synchronization, wait/join/notify, etc..
If your [M]odel will be standalone SQL (or noSQL) database, you can use observers to notify about [M]odel change and don't require context at all.

As it can be seen from `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, you should make any work with data asynchronous. No matter if data are stored online, in local databases, on filesystem or in context. Stick to this knowledge, and try to come out with your own solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't serialize the data set in question. Much of the class object variables are private and not my API. I only need the data set to live while the application/service is running. As a result I was trying to avoid the overhead of what is typically thought of as a Model (DB, files, etc...)

Comment: @garlicman I can understand that, but anyway, if you're not using Model, you will probably reach the limit of memory allocation on low-end devices very soon. That's the purpose of having Model, to keep context-data-related allocations on minimum.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate Activities and Services you could deploy a ResultReceiver or a LocalBroadcast. The Service could do the heavy work and interact with the Activity by sending its result via the metioned methods. You could hook up the Activity to the Service on the onStart and onStop methods of the Activity's Lifecycle to determine if the Activity is on foreground or not to update the UI accordingly.

Hope it helps.

NOTE: In my personal experience I have worked with both and they do a great job. I would not recommend binding to a Service because of the complexity it brings to the Activity.